# AppFabric crash when getting request from IIS website with ApplicationPoolIdentity identity

Tags: iis-7, appfabric-cache, applicationpoolidentity

I deployed a WCF in IIS7. I'm using AppFabric to cache some values. Everything work fine if I use NetWork identity( all items set into cache and get from cache successful). However, when I choose pool identity is ApplicationPoolIdentity, My AppFabric service stop working. I can't explain why. 

Base on what I read before: "The good news is that Application Pool identities also use the machine account to access network resources. No changes are required."
(http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) 
So, Can anyone tell me What happened?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have given iis server account (machine$) permissions to access the cache....

can you check if applying http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545850 on the IIS server makes a difference ?

Comment: Thank for your response. However, I did give iis server account permission to access the cache ( you see, with network identity pool, the cache works fine) So, I believe It is AppFabric bug.
[link] (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c3ed306-cc66-4b67-98f1-0c15d0919bdf/appfabric-caching-exception-the-service-does-not-allow-you-to-log-on-anonymously)